# Current site navigation showing wrong link when creating site using site template

Tags: 2013, 2010, site-collection, upgrade, current-navigation

I upgraded site collection from 2010 to 2013. It's a Team Site without publishing feature.

It contain several sub sites which were created using custom site template. All sub sites which were created in 2010 are showing correct current site navigation after upgrade. Take a look at picture below.

[image]

In above picture I am inside a subsite called `ACT01` (just an example) which is inside `Accounts` sub site.

When I mouse over `Accounts` link on left side then URL is shown as `http://myserver/Accounts/ACT01/SitePages/Accounts.aspx`

When I mouse over `Create Account` link on left side then URL is shown as
`http://myserver/Accounts/ACT01/SitePages/CreateAccount.aspx`

Same is the case with `Invoices` and `Create Invoice` links below as they are showing correct relative URL. This is the correct behavior of all ACT01, ACT02, ACT03 etc. sub sites created in 2010.

But when I create a new subsite for e.g. `ACT01` (just an example) in SP 2013 based on same custom site template then it shows `Create Account` URL incorrect.

The URL is shown as:
`http://myserver/SitePages/CreateAccount.aspx`

As you can see the URL is taking to root site. All other links in this site for e.g. `Accounts`, `Invoices` and `Create Invoice` are shown correctly i.e. they are relative to current sub site.

When I go to edit this URL in Site Navigation then this particular item is shown as disabled (see pic below).

[image]

All other links like `Accounts`, `Invoices` and `Create Invoice` are not disabled and are editable (see pic below)

[image]

I have checked and there is nothing is source code which is doing anything with site navigation while creating site.

I even deleted custom site template, then created a new one based on existing sub site (which is showing correct URL) but same issue.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I propose you eliminate the possibility that it is something carried in from your 2010 sites.  What happens when you create a new site from the 2013 team site template, add similar navigational links and backing pages, create a template, and create a new site from the new template?  Does the behavior persist?

Comment: it's strange behavior ! so at your main template , try to delete this link and add it again , then create  a site from the modified template !

Comment: @M.Qassas I did something similar suggested and it fixed the issue. First I fixed the link manually in one of the newly create sub site which was having issue. Then I deleted previous template and saved this sub site as template. Problem fixed.

Comment: @FrankMartin great job, good to hear it's solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the main site that you takes from it the main template,

- Try to fix/delete this link and add it again, then
- Save the modified site as a new template.
- Create a new site from the modified new template.